# How can I build a jar for a previous Java version?

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

I am trying to compile my code and run it on a different server. The problem is my JRE version is Java version "1.6.0_13" and that on the server is Java version "1.4.2".

This gives me "unrecognized class file version" exception when I try to run the jar on the server. I cannot compile my code on the server because of various dependencies I will have to set up.

So I need to know if there is a way to "use Eclipse" [this is easier than command line since it takes care of dependencies] and compile my stuff using 1.4.2 instead 1.6.0_13. Do I have to uninstall my JRE from my machine, then reinstall previous version and then compile or is there an elegant and cleaner way?

Comment: I would suggest you upgrade Java 6 update 13 to Java 6 update 23 as the former version is quite old and there have been many bugs fixed.  This goes 10x for Java 1.4.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should install 1.4.2 along side 1.6 on your machine, and configure that eclipse project to use the 1.4.2 JDK. Other projects may be configured to use the 1.6.

Technically you can compile to 1.4.2 compatibility with JDK 1.6, but odds are you will run into library problems, so it is not generally worth doing.

Comment: hey .. thnx. I downloaded j2sdk-1_4_2_19-linux-i586.bin . Can you tell me how can I configure eclipse to use it for my package. In eclipse I have under buildpath=>j2sdk1.4.bin and also jdk1.6.0 [if I take this out ..I get bunch of compile errors] ...while in eclipse buildpath=>orderandexport I have checked j2sdk and unchecked jdk1.6.0  ........ I tried with this but I think its not picking it up ..

Comment: I don't use eclipse much, but here are some instructions: http://www.java-forums.org/eclipse/4278-how-change-jdk.html

Answer (score 7):

You can compile for java 1.5 with the parameters

```
javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5 -bootclasspath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_21\lib\rt.jar"
```

Do not forget the bootclasspath, or you will have problems with functions like String.isEmpty() which don't exist in the java 1.5.

Answer (score 7):

### Eclipse Mars (4.5.1)

---

#### Change JDK compliance

**Window** > **Preferences** > **Java** > **Compiler** > JDK Compliance > change **Compiler compliance level:**

[image: Compiler compliance level]

If you want to change other details, you can uncheck "Use default compliance settings".

Press **OK** and in the "Compiler Settings Changed" window choose:

- **Yes** if you want to build all projects from the workspace:

  [image: Compiler Settings Changed]
- **No** if you want to build only one/some project(s) later

  - Select the project (click on the left side - E.g.: in the Package Explorer) > **Project** > **Build Project**

---

#### Export jar

**Right click** on the project (from the left side - E.g.: in the Package Explorer) > **Export...** > type "jar" to filter the options you have > choose what you want (probably **JAR file** or **Runnable JAR file**) > Next > add the details > Finish

Comment: Can you also provide a maven pom.xml example?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the Source and Target Java version in Eclipse.

Also in command line you can compile for a certain (older) Java version using -source and -target parameters:

```
javac -source 1.4 -target 1.4
```