# Get a Java program to run on a computer without modern JRE

Tags: java, compilation

I made a simple text based game that runs on my computer, but my schools computers have an older version of java and can't run it. I tried compiling the `.java` file in from the computers command prompt but I can't access where the `javac` folder is to compile because the school computer blocks everything. The command prompt is even disabled by the administrator unless I open it with a batch file. I tried wrapping the jar with the JRE in Launch4j but the exe does nothing, it loads and that's it, nothing comes up (I think it's because the text game is supposed to run in the command prompt so there is no GUI to print any of the text)

How to get a Java program to run on a computer without modern JRE?

Comment: You download the JRE...and then run it.

Comment: *This question might not even make sense*: **totally true**. *How do get a java program to run on a computer without jre*?: You simply **can't**. What you can do is recompile the program in **your** computer setting the Java version where the program might run (and cross your fingers hoping that it compiles and you don't have to change your code at all).

Comment: Why not just ask the admins for the necessary access? Schools are there for you to learn after all and they will in all likelihood provide you the necessary support...

Comment: Wait, can I do that? Like If I wanted to compile it to java 1_6_26 or something even though mine is newer? How?

Comment: @NathanTaylor use `@username` to send a response in comment for someone in the *conversation*

Comment: @AndrewThompson "SO basically if I have a .java file how would I run it on a computer without access to the jre (or without jre in general)"

Comment: @NathanTaylor What IDE if any are you using, if any?

Comment: @ Nathan Taylor : It looks like you can get exe, classes and code etc onto a machine , but not jdk.   So restriction seems to be on installing new stuff.  The JDK and JRR can be zipped and unzipped to new location. You may need to set variables like JAVA_HOME or PATH , but it does work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my schools computers have an older version of java and can't run it

Use the [cross-compilation options of `javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options) when compiling it at home.

Comment: Ok so basically I can compile it for an older version of java at home and it will run at school? You guys are freaking fast by the way....

Comment: @NathanTaylor its result from experience (and lot of time used to solve similar problems).

Comment: Aww crap! Damn you Andrew! How can you type so fast? You always beat me to it! +1

Comment: @TheLima  Well, you got bogged down trying to sort the logic of the question.  I noted one sentence, fired off an answer, then reviewed the question and cut off all the bits that made no sense.  *..I cheated.*  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are running into a bit of a contradiction here; Please take notice on what exactly you are asking:
"How can I run a **Java Program** without **Java**?"
Do you get it? You are basically asking "How can I drive a car without the car?"

---

As for the actual problem, all hope is **not** lost. Here are some options:

1. If possible by any means, simply install the latest stable version of Java on the machine.
2. From a computer that has JRE/JDK installed (or through another form of access to the JavaCompiler, AKA `JavaC`), recompile the code to the older version of Java using the command-line parameters for `source` and `target` java versions (Note: I am unsure if the JRE/JDK for the older version must be installed in the machine or not).
   For this case, you might want to take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) and/or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393249/how-can-i-build-a-jar-for-a-previous-java-version).
3. Choose another language to work with, and re-do your code into that language; You can't run Java code without Java, the same way you can't travel by train without the train to travel with.