# Eclipse: export a Runnable JAR file to be executed on an older JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

Exporting a Runnable JAR file from Eclipse is by far the quickest way to launch an Eclipse project from command line on another machine. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5441852/2091700).

A problem is that if the JRE installed on the machine you want to run from is older than the JDK used by Eclipse, you get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test_hello_world : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I know that on Eclipse I can build the project with a lower compliance level (e.g., `1.6` instead of `1.7`), but this does not seem to affect an exported JAR file.

Any idea on how to export a Runnable JAR file to be executed on an older JRE?

Answer (score 1):

This procedure seems to work for me (I tested with Java 1.2 and Eclipse Juno):

- Create a new project.
- Set the execution environment to J2SE-1.2.
- Create a main class that prints one line to System.out.
- Run the project.
- Export the runnable jar.
- Run the jar in JRE 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

By using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) you can specify any version of JRE. And in result you will get jar file build to specified version of JRE.  For example:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: I guess this involves installing Maven, and spending several hours to troubleshoot the usual configuration problems... Since exporting a JAR file is much simpler, I'm more interested in going with that solution, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the compliance level should work. You have to perform a rebuild of your project. When you export a Jar eclipse do not compile your project just for package it, it usees the already compiled files.

Comment: It does not work for me. A rebuild is performed automatically by Eclipse when changing the compliance level. Independently from the level I choose, the exported JAR file seems to be always the same (exact same number of bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Change your "Java Compiler" settings in eclipse.
Make compiler compliance level to 1.6.

[How can I build a jar for a previous Java version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393249/how-can-i-build-a-jar-for-a-previous-java-version/35174932#35174932)

Then export the 'Runnable Jar'. It will work !!

Comment: Did you read my question? _"I know that on Eclipse I can build the project with a lower compliance level (e.g., 1.6 instead of 1.7), but this does not seem to affect an exported JAR file."_

Comment: Yes, i checked your question carefully. I was also facing the same problem today. Then changing the compiler compliance level worked for me. As exporting the class files to make a jar wont compiles the source code again.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your feedback. I'll keep it into account if I run into similar issues again.

Comment: Yes, i checked your question carefully. I was also facing the same problem today. Then changing the compiler compliance level worked for me. As exporting the class files to make jar wont compiles the source code again. I will suggest once your jar is created, open your jar and make sure that class files are created with your required java version.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the compliance level and then also had to do the following:

- Right click each project and open properties->Java Build Path->Libraries
- Remove the JDK you don't want, in my case JDK 8
- Add Library -> JRE System Library -> Select the version you want, in my case 7
- Java Complier -> Set compliance level to the level you want, in my case 7
- Click ok, repeat as needed.